# Is there a way to get the most recent and the original record with a number of conditions included using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the most recent data and also the original data for each group in a table but with a set of conditions.

Below is the current structure of dataset/table.

- Each group can have multiple items
- Each item_id can have the same item_name and these are known as change item_names with one significant difference the (). The number inside defines how many iterations of changes are made.
- Each item_id can have multiple status but for the example below it is simplified to only 2 status Draft->Approved.

| group | date | item_id | item_name | status | price | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01-01 | 36FG-34-45 | AB-1234 | Draft | 15 | 100 |
| B | 2022-01-02 | 28AE-23-67 | CD-4567 | Approved | 30 | 120 |
| A | 2022-01-05 | 45RE-12-99 | DE-1234 | Approved | 20 | 300 |
| C | 2022-01-07 | 78ED-14-88 | EA-4532 | Draft | 10 | 500 |
| B | 2022-01-05 | 45AB-16-77 | CD-4567(1) | Draft | 35 | 200 |
| A | 2022-01-03 | 76JJ-98-66 | DE-1234(1) | Approved | 50 | 250 |
| A | 2022-02-02 | 17KL-10-43 | DE-1234(2) | Draft | 12 | 400 |
| C | 2022-03-03 | 97EE-42-17 | AE-2468 | Approved | 25 | 450 |

The output required: take the most recent item_id for each group & when involved in the change process and the status is not equal to approve then take the most recent item_id that has been approved for each group.

Also to note it won't necessarily be the second most recent record per group that is approved can be further back in the timeline and process.

| group | date | item_id | item_name | status | price | stock | original_item_id | original_item_name | original_status | original_price | original_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-02-02 | 17KL-10-43 | DE-1234(2) | Draft | 12 | 400 | 76JJ-98-66 | DE-1234(1) | Approved | 50 | 250 |
| B | 2022-01-05 | 28AE-23-67 | CD-4567(1) | Draft | 35 | 200 | 45AB-16-77 | CD-4567 | Approved | 30 | 120 |
| C | 2022-03-03 | 97EE-42-17 | AE-2468 | Approved | 25 | 450 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: *... when involved in the change process and the status is not equal to approve then take the most recent item_id that has been approved for each group* : I am not getting that part. What does being *involved in the change process* mean in your data? From what I see here, the result is just the latest row per group, regardless of other possible  rules.

Comment: When an item_id has brackets it is currently in the change process. In that scenario I need to retrieve the most recent item_id at status approved. Examples of this are groups A & B in the suggested output above they take the latest row per group and also in the original_ fields they also take the rows that were approved status before the most recent row. Also as I noted above it will not always be the previous row I simplified the sample data as the dataset is big.

Answer (score 0):

Your example output for group A shows the original item name (most recent item name for that group that was approved) as DE-1234(1). This has a date of 1/3/2022, however item name DE-1234 has a date of 1/5/2022 making it the most recent item id that was approved from group A. Because of that, my output differs from yours for that reference.

[Here is a link to the SQL Fiddle where I recreated this.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2860ab/52)

Here is the query I created for this:

First we create a CTE that ranks your items by group to get the most recent per group.

```
WITH cte AS--rank records by group ordered by date DESC
(
   SELECT
    [group]
    ,[date]
    ,item_id
    ,item_name
    ,status
    ,price
    ,stock
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS rn
  FROM t
 )
```

Then we get filter the CTE to only approved and re-rank to get the most recently approved by group.

```
 ,cte2 AS--rank joined records where status = approved by group ordered by date DESC
 (
  SELECT
    a.[group]
    ,a.[date]
    ,a.item_id
    ,a.item_name
    ,a.status
    ,a.price
    ,a.stock
    ,b.[group] AS original_group
    ,b.[date] AS original_date
    ,b.item_id AS original_item_id
    ,b.item_name AS original_item_name
    ,b.status AS original_status
    ,b.price AS original_price
    ,b.stock AS original_stock
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[group] ORDER BY b.rn) rn--get most recent record that was approved
  FROM cte a
  LEFT JOIN cte b ON
    a.[group] = b.[group]
    AND b.rn > a.rn--b is a previous record
    AND b.status = 'Approved'
  WHERE a.rn = 1--Most recent item id
)
```

Lastly, we query cte2 filtering for only the most recent record that was approved

```
SELECT
    [group]
    ,[date]
    ,item_id
    ,item_name
    ,status
    ,price
    ,stock
    --,original_group
    --,original_date
    ,original_item_id
    ,original_item_name
    ,original_status
    ,original_price
    ,original_stock
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1--filter for most recent record that was approved
```